# How to test if a function is defined in awk?

Tags: awk

I am writing an `awk` program and I want it to run it both with `mawk` and `gawk`.
I need a sorting function. I have written my own, but I want to use the builtin `asort()` function in `gawk` if available.

How do I know from inside my program if the `asort()` function is available ?

More generally, how can I test if a function (e.g. `gensub()`) is available ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no portable way to test if a function exists in Awk. If you're calling the Awk script from a shell, you can make Awk calls to test for the existence of functions first.

```sh
if awk 'BEGIN {asort(a)}' <>/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  define_asort=
else
  define_asort='
function asort() { … }
'
fi
awk "$define_asort"'
  … rest of script …
'
```

If you're only trying to distinguish GNU Awk from others, you can test on some other GNU Awk feature. Calling an undefined functions causes a fatal error in Awk, but using an undefined variable is always fine and returns an empty value. You can in particular use `PROCINFO[version]`, which since Gawk 3.1.4 contains the Gawk version number.

```
function my_sort(a) { … }
function sort_wrapper(a) { if (PROCINFO["version"]) asort(a); else my_sort(a); }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest an hack to determine if you are running `mawk` or `gawk`. Here it is

```
BEGIN {
  file = ARGV[0] " -W version 2>&1 | head -1"
  file | getline
  if ($1 == "mawk")
    print "mawk"
  else if ($2 == "Awk")
    print "gawk"
  close(file)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {has_asort = (asort (x)) == "0"}
     function my_asort(a) {
       if (has_asort) return asort (a)
       ...
     }
     ...
```

Note that the space between `asort` and `(x)` is important. With it, in `awk` implementations that don't support `asort()`, that's interpreted as the `asort` variable concatenated to the `x` one. Without it, you'd get an error about the `asort()` function not existing.

So we can tell if `asort()` is supported here by invoking it on an undefined array `x` in which case it returns `0`, while in `awk`'s that don't support it, that's the concatenation of two undefined variables which yields the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for gawk 5.0.1 under Ubuntu 20.04; YMMV:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
@load "rwarray" # just to show how extensions look
function DoSomething(a, b){
  return a * b
}
BEGIN {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" # options are @unsorted, @ind_str_asc, @ind_num_asc, @val_type_asc, @val_str_asc, @val_num_asc; also ..._desc
  for(_key in PROCINFO["identifiers"]){
    _val = PROCINFO["identifiers"][_key]
    if(_val ~ /scalar$/) { continue }
    if(_val ~ /array$/) { continue }
    if(_val ~ /untyped$/) { continue }
    if(_val ~ /builtin$/) { continue } # It Depends (tm) - do you want builtin functions or not?
    print _key " = " _val
  }
}
```

It prints:

```
DoSomething = user
reada = extension
writea = extension
```

or

```
DoSomething = user
and = builtin
asort = builtin
asorti = builtin
atan2 = builtin
bindtextdomain = builtin
close = builtin
compl = builtin
cos = builtin
dcgettext = builtin
dcngettext = builtin
exp = builtin
fflush = builtin
gensub = builtin
gsub = builtin
index = builtin
int = builtin
isarray = builtin
length = builtin
log = builtin
lshift = builtin
match = builtin
mktime = builtin
or = builtin
patsplit = builtin
rand = builtin
reada = extension
rshift = builtin
sin = builtin
split = builtin
sprintf = builtin
sqrt = builtin
srand = builtin
strftime = builtin
strtonum = builtin
sub = builtin
substr = builtin
system = builtin
systime = builtin
tolower = builtin
toupper = builtin
typeof = builtin
writea = extension
xor = builtin
```